# How to find the number of continuous times a character appears in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, google-bigquery

I have a string `11111122111131111111`

I want to create an array of the number of times 1 appears continuously i.e. first 6 characters are 1s -> two 2's -> four 1's -> one 3 -> seven 1's

So the output that i want is  `[6,4,7]`

I know how to find the number of times a character appears in a string but how to find the numbers of times they appear in a contiguous patter.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.  I don't know of any database that actually implement "standard" SQL.

Comment: Please mention using RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '11111122111131111111' line
)
SELECT line, ARRAY(SELECT LENGTH(e) FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(line, r'1+')) e) result
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
[
  {
    "line": "11111122111131111111",
    "result": [
      "6",
      "4",
      "7"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

A little unclear as to the actual RDBMS

Here we use an ad-hoc tally table (any table of adequate size will do).  Then we apply a standard Gaps-and-Islands.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(500) = '11111122111131111111'
Declare @C varchar(10)  = '1'


Select Seq=Row_Number() over (Order by Seq)
      ,Cnt=count(*)
 From (
        Select N
              ,S = substring(@S,N,1)
              ,Seq = N - Row_Number() over (Order by N)
         From ( Select Top (len(@S)) 
                       N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
                  From master..spt_values n1
              ) A
         Where substring(@S,N,1)=@C
      ) A
 Group By Seq
 Order By Seq
```

**Returns**

```
Seq Cnt
1   6
2   4
3   7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH splitString(val) AS       
(
    -- convert the string to xml, seperating the elements by spaces
    SELECT    CAST('<r><i>' + REPLACE(@string,' ','</i><i>') + '</i></r>' AS XML)
)
SELECT  [Key],
        COUNT(*) [WordCount]
FROM    (   -- select all of the values from the xml created in the cte
            SELECT  p.value('.','varchar(100)') AS [Key]
            FROM    splitString
                    CROSS APPLY val.nodes('//i') t (p)) AS t
GROUP BY [Key]
```